# phone wants to install something

Tags: applications

A friend of mine has a mpie m8. I think it had a virus so i factory reset it. Now my phone wants desperately to install com.google.system.s. i installed it without knowing what it is. I downloaded 360 antivirus and it said that it is malware. I uninstalled it (i sweated to do this). And now every 5 seconds it tries to install it again. I cancel it every time. What should i do? Whatis com.google.system.s?

Comment: Related: [Device wants desperately to install a package (com.google.system.s) on its own](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/128862/)

Answer (score 0):

Go to application manager in setting and search for an app that you feel strange. Then uninstall it. This is you who can also force stop it.