# Device wants desperately to install a package (com.google.system.s) on its own

Tags: malware

I have in my hands a Mpie M8 device (Android 5), The previous owner said it wasn't working properly and I suspected it had a virus. I factory reset it and now the phone wants desperately to install `com.google.system.s` every 5 seconds even though I press cancel and even though I have WiFi off. I install it and it said that it is about locking. The phone started restarting all the time. I downloaded 360 Security and it said this is malware.

I tried to uninstall it and it said that this app is deep in my phone. I finally uninstall it (with a lots of sweat). And I have the same problem again, every 5 seconds. What is this file? What should I do?

Comment: Based from [this page](http://www.bestappsmarket.com/p/app?appId=2041898&title=com-google-system-s), it seems it's removed as malware. However, I couldn't find any info about this malware...

Comment: I couldn't find anything in internet either. I don't know what to do. I can't do anything. I can't use any app. This device has a non-removable launcher and all the time it says "loading launcher". When the launcher is loading the phone wants to install this and "launcher stopped working" and "play store stopped working" and "news365 stopped working" etc etc. This happends every some seconds..

Comment: I just found the [VirusTotal report](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/ca960dd49977ceb4a4df73463c0953b897418a6580c4a2117f764a369636d68e/analysis/) for this malware. Hopefully, it can give some more insight to nuke it.

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/139768/i-am-being-forced-to-download-random-apps

Answer (score 2):

From experience, flashing in any conventionally accepted way instantaneously bricks this Mpie M8. It takes a lot of efforts to unbrick it, too. So work with what you have, root it first so that the malware can be managed. When the auto-installation-without-permission starts, pull down notification and click on app info to see which system process is being hijacked and disable it immediately. As an example, mine shows Launcher and Android Service are involved. Have used a different launcher instead just to be on the safe side. Android Service, hiding in /system/priv-app as android_service_800000_0923_outsea.apk, appears the true culprit. Once deleted, the phone runs flawlessly. Of course your phone may have different malware in it depending on which malicious websites that you have visited. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Settings → Security → Device Administrators and uncheck  `COM.GOOGLE.SYSTEM.S`. Now you can uninstall it.

Comment: OP wrote: "*I finally uninstall it (with a lots of sweat)*" (sic) and then noted "*I have the same problem again, every 5 seconds. What is this file? What should I do?*". Your answer has not addressed the question correctly. Please revise it.