# Is there any android apk or process info library website/database?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, malware

I have a virus on Micromax canvas A104 and is on deep system(with root privilege) level. I tried removing it on safe mode, resetting the phone etc.

I rooted my canvas a104 rooted to find the virus source. But there are many System app which i can’t differentiate and find it risky to remove the core apps.

I want to know any database where i can get info about all my apps and process(like [https://processlibrary.com](http://processlibrary.com) where you can find info on windows processes).

My problem is similar to these threads:

1. [Device wants desperately to install a package (com.google.system.s) on its own](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/128862/device-wants-desperately-to-install-a-package-com-google-system-s-on-its-own)
2. [How to remove a Virus that installs an unlimited amount of APPs causing the smartphone to stop once an internet connection has been established?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/134927/how-to-remove-a-virus-that-installs-an-unlimited-amount-of-apps-causing-the-smar)

I have gone through many other threads but couldn't find anything useful.

One solution for this can be custom rom. But i didn't find any stable ROM and find it risky for my phone.

Any help on this or a solution to the problem will also be appreciated!!

Comment: If your aim is to only get rid of the virus, simpler would be to take backup of your data ( easier now that device IS rooted), locate reliable stock ROM download or get the service center to flash it . It is very unlikely that you would get a *library* you are seeking for and when if you did, you would require ROM chef's knowledge to isolate the culprit. Not worth the effort. +1 for diligence and spadework before asking the question- welcome to Android enthusiasts

Comment: I see [stock ROM](https://androidmtk.com/download-micromax-stock-rom-models) for your device here and I believe it is a good source . Can't vouch as I never used any mtk devices

Comment: Thanks for the the answer. I have been to that link but didn't find any reviews for these ROMs. I find this [link](http://forums.androidcentral.com/optimus-v-rooting-roms-hacks/156703-guide-apk-s-their-purpose-safe-not-remove-big.html) somewhat useful. But there were processes which were not there.

Comment: You could edit your question to include all the names of system apps installed in your device, I might help you catch the culprit..

Comment: There may be dormant malicious system apps also (which are not currently running, so not a process). So include all system apps by `pm list packages -s` and `pm list packages -f -s`